# std::declval() firing assertion error with warnings in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Consider this snippet:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <typename U>
auto foo() -> decltype(std::declval<U>() + std::declval<U>());

template <typename T>
decltype(foo<T>()) bar(T)
{}

int main()
{
    bar(1);
    return 0;
}
```

This fires a warning *and* a static assertion failure in all versions of GCC I tried it on (4.7.3, 4.8.1, 4.9-some-git) when compiled with `-Wall -Wextra`. For instance, this is the output of 4.8.1:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘decltype (foo<T>()) bar(T) [with T = int; decltype (foo<T>()) = int]’:
main.cpp:12:7:   required from here
main.cpp:8:2: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 {}
  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/utility:70,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘typename std::add_rvalue_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type std::declval() [with _Tp = int; typename std::add_rvalue_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type = int&&]’:
main.cpp:8:2:   required from ‘decltype (foo<T>()) bar(T) [with T = int; decltype (foo<T>()) = int]’
main.cpp:12:7:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/type_traits:1871:7: error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
       static_assert(__declval_protector::__stop,
```

If one either disables the warnings *or* supplies `bar` with a return statement, e.g.,

```cpp
template <typename T>
decltype(foo<T>()) bar(T a)
{
    return a + a;
}
```

the assertion failure disappears. Clang++ 3.3 does not fire assertion errors in any case. Is this standard-conforming behaviour from GCC?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9e655ce1ed0091bb133d8eb8af392515-9a9914b3e2b7ed07c206d6accecccdb6).

Comment: Well, not returning from a function with non-void return type is undefined behaviour, so both compilers are right.

Comment: @AndyProwl: You added a statement to `bar`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: still, if I wrap the UB so that it does not actually ever gets executed the program should still be well formed? how is this any different from compiling code that dereferences a null pointer? I was under the impression UB should still compile.

Comment: You cannot "wrap UB". UB is UB. It goes forward and backward in time, like Paul Atreides. (Eventually the overwhelming amount of UB in the world will cause us all to go on a rampage and purge all computers from the face of the world.)

Comment: @aschepler: Right, I did that to eliminate the warning, because I thought the error was unrelated to the warning. Silly me.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not sure I get it. If I write ``if (false) *nullptr;`` is the compiler allowed to refuse compiling?

Comment: @KerrekSB: bah nevermind my garbage, probably I meant something like ``if (false) *(int *)(nullptr);``

Comment: @bluescarni: I don't think that's undefined behaviour. You're not *doing* anything with the expression. It's OK for example to say `typeid(*p)`, no matter the value of `p`. Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is another case where you get UB. Similarly, if you removed `bar(1);` from your code, it would compile. And `return foo<int>();` also compiles.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is not valid to do `typeid(*p)` if `p` is null or uninitialized or dangling.

Comment: @aschepler: Good point. `p` has to be a valid pointer or null.

Comment: The upshot is, there are different kinds of UB. Some are dynamic, depending on execution paths, and others are only the result of the source code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `typeid(*a_nullptr)` throws an exception, per standard.

Comment: @Xeo: Which is not UB!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My copy of GCC 4.9 built in early June compiles it without complaint as long as I add `return {};` or `throw;` inside the function. With no `return`, it does fire that static assertion. This is certainly a bug, but only a minor one, since the function only "crashes" upon execution.

I have seen that error when trying to execute `declval()` in a constant expression, so something like that may be happening in your case. The "cannot be used" is presumably referring to ODR-use or using the result.

Perhaps in the absence of any statement it tried to manufacture one with the content of the `decltype`. Adding even a simple statement like `0;` silences the spurious error. (But `static_assert( true, "" )` or even `void(0)` are insufficient.)

Filed a [GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57857).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe a compiler is within its rights to fail to compile this program; a fatal error for this program is, IME, nonconforming.  (The warning, OTOH, is perfectly fine.  A compiler can warn about missing return statements, weird inheritance idioms, British/American spelling in identifiers, or racist comments in string literals if it wants, provided it actually compiles valid programs.)

I believe your program produces undefined behavior when run, since you unconditionally execute a function that fails to return a value.  However, I don't think that excuses a compiler from actually compiling this program; for all it knows, you compile the program, copy the executable to a tape back-up, and never look at it again.  Additionally, I expect that if the compiler emits an error for this program, it would likely emit an error for a program that only called `bar()` after checking that `argc==1`, and that certainly would not be within the compiler's UB rights.

Strictly speaking, a compiler doesn't have to be conforming in all circumstances to be considered conforming.  A conforming compiler merely has to be able to compile any valid C++ program.  Since you can compile this program without `-Wall`, it can be argued that GCC is conformant without that flag passed.  It is surprising that enabling warnings would result in nonconforming errors, though, so I would lean towards characterizing this as a conformance issue in GCC.

Comment: @Potatoswatter *In My Estimation*.